# Как правильней встроить Javascript в php?

Tags: javascript, html, php

Хочу сделать так, что когда пользователь нажимает на ссылку и ему появляется промт окно:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var delete=prompt("Что бы подтвердить удаление введите слово "удалить", ""))
if(delete=="удалить")
  тут выполняем часть пхп скрипта
else
  тут тоже выполняем часть пхп скрипта

</script>
```

Кто знает, как правильно такое реализовать??

Comment: C помощью AJAX

Comment: @zhenyab, согласен, другие варианты нецелесообразно использовать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
js:
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#delete").click(function(){
var delete=promt("Что бы подтвердить удаление введите слово 'удалить'", "");
if(delete=="удалить") $.get("action.php", "data=1");
});

});
</script>

php:
<?
include('db.php'); // пусть тут лежать подключения к базе данных
$data = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['data']);
mysql_query('DELETE FROM `table_name` WHERE `id`='.$data);
?>
```

Comment: вставил - ссылку кнопк перед скриптом но при клике окно не высвечивается оО

    <a id="delete" href="#">Click me</a>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#delete").click(function(){
    var delete=promt("Что бы подтвердить удаление введите слово   'удалить'", "");
    if(delete=="удалить") $.get("action.php", "data=1");
    });

    });
    </script>

Comment: Во-первых delete - это оператор. Его нельзя использовать как переменную. Во-вторых не "promt", а "prompt". На всякий случай, вот работающий код:
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#delete").click(function(){
    var del=prompt("Что бы подтвердить удаление введите слово   'удалить'", "");
    if(del=="удалить") $.get("action.php", "data=1");
});

    });
    </script>
    <a id="delete" href="#">Click me</a>

Comment: все равно не высвечивается((

Comment: бред. полностью весь код скиньте.

Comment: !DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Страничка</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#delete").click(function(){
    var del=prompt("Что бы подтвердить удаление введите слово     'удалить'", "");
    if(del=="удалить") $.get("action.php", "data=1");
    });

    });
    </script>
    <a id="delete" href="#">Click me</a>
    </body>
    </html>

Comment: лично мое мнение - неплохо бы было подключить jQuery перед использованием.